# Matriz que contenga numeros y nombres

Tags: bluej

estoy recién aprendiendo a programar en java, en blueJ, necesito crear un código para calcular el sueldo de trabajadores y al final imprimir los datos de cada trabajador (nombre, rut, contrato, etc) en una matriz, he estado intentando hacer la matriz para que imprima 4 datos, pero el blueJ me arroja solo nullnullnullnull, no se que hacerle para que funcione o de que manera tengo que hacerlo para que imprima una matriz que tenga numeros y caracteres, les dejo mi código

```
public class Trabajador
```

{

```
public static void getDatos (){
    String rut;
    String nombre ;
    String contrato;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese numeros de trabajadores");
    int j = leer.nextInt();
    String matriz [][] = new String [j][4];
    int y=0;

for(int i=0; i < j; i++){
     System.out.println ("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");
     nombre = leer.next();
     nombre = matriz [i][0];
     System.out.println("Ingrese el rut sin guión");
     rut = leer.next();
     rut = matriz [i][1];
     System.out.println("¿Que tipo de contrato tiene? a.partTime b.Contrato c.Planta");
     contrato = leer.next();
     contrato = matriz [i][2];
    }
for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++){
  for(y=0; y < matriz[x].length; y++){
    System.out.print(matriz[x][y]);


  }
     }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian, probé el código en netbeans, otra IDE, los cambios a realizar son:

1.- El largo de la matriz debe ser [j][3], ya que son 3 datos los que pides (nombre, rut y tipo de contrato)

2.- El programa arroja null por que estás asignando a las variables nombre, rut y contrato, la matriz, y es al revés. Debería quedar así al arreglarlo:

```
         matriz [i][0] = nombre;
         matriz [i][1] = rut;
         matriz [i][2] = contrato;
```

Saludos y suerte :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora creo que a la matriz se le asignó bien los datos, ahora el problema que se me genera que como el rut son numeros y la matriz es de string, me rechaza numeros, entonces estoy en ese dilema, porque si el arreglo lo dejo como int me va a pasar el mismo error con el nombre y contrato, entonces como puedo hacer para que me acepte tanto String como int? le puse 4 columnas al arreglo para dejar el sueldo en la ultima que la tengo en otra clase

Comment: En el código tienes definido el rut como String, ¿lo cambiaste?. Si lo cambiaste lo que puedes hacer es realizar una conversión de datos de la siguiente manera:                                                                                                     matriz[i][1] = String.ValueOf(rut);